# How to do a sequential SSH to a server using a batch of commands

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm working on a db server but I must ssh many times to access to it. Something like this:

```
step1) ssh xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx
pw: xxx

step2) ssh yyy@yyy.yyy.yyy
pw:yyy

step3) sudo mysqlsh
pw:zzzz

step4) mysql -u root -paaaa
use mydb;
```

How to run these commands in a sequence? I want to create a script batch to do it. How to do it?

Update:
Itried to do this but doesn't work. It just log in the first time.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

spawn ssh xxx@xxx
expect "*password:"
send "xxx\r";
interact

expect "*$ "
spawn ssh yyy@yyy
expect "*password:"
send "yyy\r";
interact
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out linux command "[expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)".

Comment: Ditto, I use expect for this.

Comment: Can you post the script to do the above 4 steps?

Comment: I read it and try hard. Your solution can't shh in sequence for sure because "expect" just do at the first level. After logging in xxx@xxx, it can't ssh continuously.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see "expect" as giving up, though I have been known to essentially rewrite expect in python to wrap something I don't have source code to.

I'd suggest:
Steps 1&2: Use passwordless, passphraseless DSA keys.
Step 3: /etc/sudoers can be modified to make sudo not require a password.
Step 4: Looks like you're already there.